# Negative binomial distribution (a, b, 0)-class

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

Show that the negative binomial distribution is in the (a, b, 0)-class and determine the parameters a and b for a negative binomial distribution with mean 12 and variance 17.

Wich tools I have to use to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have your explicit distribution, I think you can directly calculate $p_{k+1}/p_{k}$ so you can get $a$ and $b$.

From then you have a way friendlier expression for your distribution which would allow to get the mean and the variance depending from $a$ and $b$

Comment: Could you explain me what is  pk+1/pk ? That's not familiar to me

Comment: Oh sorry. Actually you can model every distribution On ${N}$ by defining ${P}(B=k) = p_k$ where $B$ is your variable . And then $(a, b, 0)$ distributions are defined by $p_{k+1}/p_k = a + b/k$. Which you can solve because $p_k$ are known for your distribution.

Comment: Sorry it is $p_{k+1}/p_k = a + b/(k+1)$